# LRU with shared_ptr in multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr

I run into a corner case while using a shared_ptr based "database" that doubles as an LRU.

Since C++17, the `shared_ptr::use_count` is imprecise, so I have trouble deciding on which elements can be safely removed from the LRU.

I cannot remove still-in-use elements, as that would break contracts in the rest of the code.

As far as I understand it locking a mutex is not enough, since only a mutex unlock will force a memory barrier. I could still read an outdated value even when holding the lock.

I could of course slap a memory barier after I lock a mutex inside the LRU, but I'm a bit worried about the performance impact.

Here is an outline of how the lru works:

```
template <k,v>
class DB{
  shared_ptr<V> emplace(k, args...) {
    lock guard();
    remove_elements_if_needed();
    insert_if_new(k, args...);
    refresh_lru(k);
    return ptr;
  }
};
```

Comment: I doubt you need a memory barrier if you are using a mutex correctly.  But this question is way too vague for anyone to help.   `There is a high-level race condition, where after removing a still-in-use element that element could be re-created by another thread breaking uniqueness contracts.` - you need to elaborate on this detail and show a lot more code.

Comment: @selbie Changed the wording. This part is not relevant to this question.

Comment: I have some ideas.  But can you show real code that could serve as a [mcve] instead of pseduo-code? What is `k`, `v`, and `V` in this context?

Comment: Preferably show your `remove_elements_if_needed` function verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution I'd propose is while under a lock, identify a candidate element to remove.  Then attempt to remove it by doing this:

- Create a weak_ptr instance to an element you think might be a good
  candidate to remove
- Delete the item from the list as you normally would
- Try to restore the item as a shared_ptr from the weak_ptr
- If you promote the weak_ptr back to shared_ptr and it's still null,
  then you are done.
- If the new shared_ptr is not null, then you know someone still has a
  reference to the item.  Put the item back into your data structure
  exactly as you found it.

Something like this.  Since I don't have your code yet, I'm winging it wrt to your implementation.  But I'm guessing you have a collection of "nodes". Each node has a member that is the shared_ptr instance that you hand back to callers.

```
 bool remove_unused_element() {

      bool removed = false;

      for (node& n : lru) {
          weak_ptr<X> wp = n.item;
          n.item.reset();
          shared_ptr<X> sp = wp.lock();
          if (sp != nullptr){
              n.item = sp ; // restore this node, someone is still using it
          }
          else {
              lru.erase(n);
              removed = true;
              break;
          }
     }
     return removed;
}             
          
          
void remove_elements_if_needed() {
    bool result = true;
    while ((lru.size() > max_lru_size) && result) {
         result = remove_unused_element();
    }
}
```

All of the above code assumes you have acquired the mutex as you show in your pseudo code.

Comment: Just a quick question, why the reference? I would write it as `shared_ptr<X> sp2(wp.lock()); if (sp2 != nullptr) { n.item = std::move(sp2); }`

Comment: That's a typo.  I had refactored that from an earlier implementation in which `sp1` was a reference to item.  I changed.